# Search Bar with Segmented Control Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a search bar and a segmented control that will filter out the different types of results in a table view.

But what im facing is that the segment control bar, goes down whenever i search a result. (Which means i have to scroll down in order to access the segmented bar) I want it to remain right below the search bar. Is that possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, add the searchBar as subview on top of view then add the segmented as subview of view and finally to show results in a table add the table in subview of main view, thats so simple.

[image]

Comment: Does that requires any codings?